# save correctly my DataFrame

Tags: python, csv, pandas, for-loop, return

I wrote a code that computes some values from columns derived from a csv file. The results are saving as a columns in an old file .csv where all results are accumulated.
The thing is that I choose which column is used to run my function, Now I'm trying to automatize my analysis using a list indicating which columns to analyze. The code run successfully and I can see the results on the shell. The problem is that when I open the csv file, only the last column is saved. I'm using the `mode='a'` in `to_csv` so I think that is a problem of my iteration.

My code is the following:

```
df=pd.read_csv('document.csv')



df2 = df.set_index(['COLUMN_A'])

M=[1,3,4,5]
for i in M:

    dfT = df2.loc[i]


    N = int(len(dfT))
    max_time = np.float(N*(0.160))
    frames = np.float(max_time/N)
    t_step=np.float(frames)

    data = pd.DataFrame({'N':[N],'max_time':[max_time],'frames':[frames]})

    print(data)

    t=np.linspace(0.160, max_time, N)


    def alldisplacement(df1, frames, coords=['POSITION_X', 'POSITION_Y']):


        tau = t.copy()
        shifts = np.floor(tau / t_step).astype(np.int)
        msds_sum = np.zeros(shifts.size)
        delta_inv = np.arange(N+1)
        delta = delta_inv[N:0:-1]
        lag = np.arange(1,N+1)


        for i, shift in enumerate(shifts):
            diffs = dfT[coords] - dfT[coords].shift(-shift)
            sqdist = np.square(diffs).sum(axis=1)
            msds_sum[i] = sqdist.sum()
            msd = np.divide(msds_sum,delta)


        msds = pd.DataFrame({'msd':msd})
        return msds

    msd = alldisplacement(dfT, frames, coords=['POSITION_X', 'POSITION_Y'])

    print(msd)    


#msd.to_csv('/Users/Computer/Desktop/Examples anaconda/new.csv', sep=',',mode='a', index=False)

b = msd[i]
a = pd.read_csv('new.csv')
c = pd.concat ([a,b],axis=1, ignore_index=True)
c.to_csv('/Users/Computer/Desktop/Examples anaconda/new.csv', sep=',',mode='a', index=False)
```

at the end it appears a problem showing:

```
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)

  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)

KeyError: 5
```

Which correspond to the last value that I chose in M

Comment: Just a general bit of advice, defining a function within a for loop is bad practice and probably unnecessary and more inefficient than creating it outside the loop and calling when needed. And, you're using the same variable, `i`, as the iterator for the loop within a loop, a definite no-no - which is almost definitely why you're having issues at the end when you call `msd[i]`. Also, it's hard to tell the issue with the data without the data. Can you post the head of your initial df?

Comment: Once you fix those issues, try re-running your code and if your still having problems, edit your question with the cleaned up code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did notice that `i` as iterator was repetead. Now, I don't know if is the efficient way to do it, but it works!